# Does the Android 3 & 4 browser no longer use intents for each page it opens?

Tags: android, browser, android-intent, intentfilter

On Android 2, the browser creates and opens an intent for each webpage you click on in the browser, thereby giving you the ability of using different apps to open a specific link (if those apps have properly configured intent filters).  However, I noticed that in Android 3 & 4 this doesn't seem to be the case anymore: The browser doesn't seem to generate any intents when you click and open a link in the browser. Can anyone confirm if this is indeed the case (and not an issue just on my end)?  I'm also wondering if there is a solution for this or work around?  For example if I click on www.facebook.com I'd like to be able to use a custom app to open that link instead of using the browser; that's what I'm able to do with my app on Android 2 with properly configured intent filters.